# Utility to exponse an EnumSet as an existance map (Map<? extends Enum, Boolean>)?

Tags: java, spring, collections, apache-commons

I am using Spring to bind user input into a command object. Unfortunately it does not seem to support EnumSets (giving an Exception "Could not instantiate Collection type: java.util.EnumSet"), so I am thinking about creating a utility that provides a "view" for any Set as a Map.

I am just wondering is anyone aware of anything that already does this either in Spring or in Commons Lang/Collections/etc ?

Comment: How do you instantiate the EnumSet?

Comment: @Puce Normally you'd have to call one of the static factory methods, but what Spring is trying to do is to instantiate an instance via reflection in order to do some internal manipulation.

Comment: Again, please show us the relevant code/ Spring configuration, which results in the exception you mentioned.